# How combine multiple regex patterns?

Tags: regex

I am building a regex that should meet the following requirements:

1. match a question mark, when on the first position of the string (only on first position)
2. match all digits

**String:**

```txt
?A flower and 33 trees?
```

**Regex:**

```txt
^[?[:digit:]]
```

[Test on Regex101](https://regex101.com/?regex=%5E%5B?%5B:digit:%5D%5D&testString=?A%20flower%20and%2033%20trees?&flags=%3Cflags%3E&subst=%3Creplacement%3E&delimiter=%3Cdelimiter%3E)

The mentioned regex pattern only matches the question mark on the first position, but doesn't match the digits. How can we combine multiple regex patterns?

Comment: Your attempt matches any sequence of digits and question marks starting at the beginning of the line. It's not clear from the question's contents whether you want to match these in sequence, or either a question mark at the beginning of a line or a digit anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The pattern should match a question mark at the beginning of a line AND match all digits (anywhere). The final should look like `A flower and trees?`.

Comment: As highlighted in the [tag:regex] tag description when you select it, and often repeated in comments, you have to be more explicit about which specific regex engine you need help with.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks, I promise a more spcific description in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution:

```
^[?]|[[:digit:]]
```

I can't explain why an alternation with vertical bar is the solution. For my understanding alternatiion match a single regular expression out of several possible regular expressions - not multiple regular expressions out of several possible regular expressions.

Do I miss a important thing?

Comment: No, this matches a question mark at the beginning of a line, _or_ a digit anywhere.

Comment: Your question is unclear; perhaps that's actually what you are asking for? Probably then `[[:digit:]]+` to match all consecutive digits as one group.

Comment: The regex only matches one occurrence of something, but your test adds a `g` flag which says to try again after the first match until it can find no more.

Comment: Is it possible, that some Regex engines work with default value `g` flag? Because I tested the pattern with the vertical bar alternation on a SAP HANA system and it worked fine.

Comment: You would have to consult their documentation. Generally the regex itself is traditional but the external tooling provides additional frills. So for example, in Python, `re.match` applies the regex once, while `regex.findall` applies it as many times as possible.